# Recursive integral equation with different variables

Tags: calculus, recursion

$$S = \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \ddots}}}$$

I know that these kind of recursive questions are one inside another - meaning that:

$$ S = \frac{1}{\int_1^2 S}$$

The question is what is the variable? $x$ ? $ S$ ? whatever I would like it to be?

If the variable is $x$ (or anything else than $S$ ) then the answer is:

$$ S (x \mid _1^2) = S = 1 \Rightarrow S = 1$$

If the variable is $S$ than the answer is:

$$ S ( \frac{S^2}{2}  \mid _1^2 ) = S[ 2 - 0.5] = 1.5S = 1 \Rightarrow S = \frac{2}{3}$$

Which is correct? I assume there is only one value that is correct and not $2$ because, this integral keeps on forever so we don't *actually* know if it is $dx$ or $dS$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S = \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\int_1^2 \ddots}}}$$
if the right side is anything, it is a value at least in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, so $S$ is not a variable.
Said this I would procede this way:

$$S = \frac{1}{\int_1^2 Sdx} \iff S^2 = \frac{1}{\int_1^2 dx}= 1 \iff S=\pm 1.$$
I actually have no idea if the negative solution is acceptable.